# how to clear form after successful submit ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to make the contact form disappear after successful submission but am not sure how to go about it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {

        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactfinal.php",
            data: str,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#submit").hide();
                 $("#loading").show();
                  },
            success: function(response) {
               $('#error').html(response);
                $("#submit").show();
                $("#loading").hide();

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#ajax-contact-form").hide()` ?

Comment: Where would I put that in relation to the code? I think I tried that but it hide the form when there were error messages as well which obviously won't be good.

Comment: In ajax success callback.

Comment: I added that line right under $("#loading").hide(); and it hides the form even if not correctly filled in i.e.: the user leaves out a required field.

Comment: That's because you do not have any client side validation.

Comment: I do, it's in a different .php file called contactfinal.php as called in the ajax

Comment: Do you have validations on server side? You need to call `.hide()` as per the response from the server.

Comment: Yes, I have php validation in contactfinal.php as being called per the ajax code

Comment: @ShadowWizard, sorry. I see you said client side. No, I only have server side validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you perform server side validation, you should check if the response is empty, then hide the form:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#error').html(response);
    if (!response || response.length == 0)
        $("#ajax-contact-form").hide();
```

That's the ideal way, however based on seeing your source code, you need a "hack":

```
if (!response || response.length == 0 || response.indexOf("Your message was sent") >= 0)
        $("#ajax-contact-form").hide();
```

Comment: should your last line not have .hide() in it?

Comment: Unfortunately  the form still shows after submitting properly

Comment: @Jonathan if you add `alert(response.length);` what you see? You might have spaces there or something like that.

Comment: @Jonathan that means you get response from the server. So back to base 1. How can you tell there is validation error from the server, and when the input is valid i.e. submission was a success?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115603/discussion-between-jonathan-and-shadow-wizard).